# @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" ) when using generic wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a List of objects which are an extension of the Model object. The instances are created with the given Class object.

```
public class ModelFactory {
    public static final List< ? extends Model > createList( final int pLength,
            final Class< ? extends Model > pModelClass ) {
        List< Model > models = new ArrayList< Model >( pLength );
        try {
            for ( int i = 0; i < pLength; i++ ) {
                Model model = pModelClass.newInstance();
                models.add( i, model );
            }
        } catch ( InstantiationException e ) {
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
        }
        return models;
    }
}
```

When I try to call the method, it all works fine. I do however get a warning, which I now suppress.

```
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    List< CarModel > list = ( List< CarModel > ) ModelFactory.createList(
            4, CarModel.class );
```

Do any of you guys know of a solution to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of it by giving the type a name, e.g.

```
public static final <T extends Model> List<T> createList( final int pLength,
        final Class<T> pModelClass ) {
    List< T > models = new ArrayList< T >( pLength );
    ...
}
```

This will get a bit messy when `T` itself is generic, but as long as it isn't, this gives you additional type safety. Right now, you do actually *not* guarantee that the list you return contains objects of the type you put in (which is why you need the cast).

So in your code, the first `? extends Model` and second `? extends Model` are **not the same type**. As a rule of thumb a `?` is always unique. In fact, your code will always return a `List<Model>`, independent of the actual class that you pass.

You should then be able to use it like this:

```
List< CarModel > list = ModelFactory.createList( 4, CarModel.class );
```

Note that I not only got rid of the warning, but also of the cast.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and clear answer. It helped me understand what was going on more clearly. I actually had another helper method like this: private static void invokeMethods( Model pModel ) but a quick change to the following made that blend in nicely: private static < T > void invokeMethods( T pModel ). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Model {}
public class CarModel extends Model {}
public class Foo {
    void bar() {
    List< CarModel > list = ModelFactory.createList(
            4, CarModel.class );
    }
}
public class ModelFactory {
    public static final <T extends Model> List<T> createList( final int pLength,
            final Class< T > pModelClass ) {
        List< T > models = new ArrayList< T >( pLength );
        try {
            for ( int i = 0; i < pLength; i++ ) {
                T model = pModelClass.newInstance();
                models.add( i, model );
            }
        } catch ( InstantiationException e ) {
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
        }
        return models;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input as well! And for future reference, this answer contains the missing line of code that needs adjustment, which was omitted  in the accepted answer: `T model = pModelClass.newInstance();`. This adjustment should be kind of obvious though. ;)